# JBoss AS 6&7 - need to automate operations in java application

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I need to be able to control JBoss operations from java application.
I've spent the past several hours reading about this matter, and it seems like there is a major differences between AS6 to AS7 in this area.

To my understanding, and please correct me if I'm wrong, the Twiddle tool was used in AS6 and a CLI is used in AS7 to automate operations via command line

I was wondering:

1. is there a way to to write a java application that support both versions?
2. if I write different applicatoins for working with AS6 and AS7, 
   will the Twiddle and the CLI allow the following operations:

   - query server configuration
   - deploy/start/stop application
   - deploy datasource
   - start/stop server
   - Check application list
   - get application state
   - deploy JMS resource
   - add/remove user

If you can refer me to good tutorials/examples I'd be grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use this kind of tool everyday in my Administration Java EE jobs :)

[it's BuildProcess](http://sourceforge.net/projects/buildprocess/) which became an apache project named [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/) and does exactly all you exlpain here.

With this one I can manage deployment  on JBoss / WebLogic / WebSphere for EAR / WAR / JAR ; in fact there is no limitation ; you can even manage the deployement of config file etc... ; you can do everything with it.

I manage 140 customer environment with it.

Hope this could help.

Comment: thanks for your answer. the code I need to write will be distributed to clients so I'm looking for  a solution like: jmx, using command lines with twiddle, etc. i'm just no familiar with these options so I was wondering if they can give me all the functionality i need and if I can interact with both versions the same way. thanks

Comment: You can have a look at the documentation of Apache Karaf and [ask your specific question on their forum](http://karaf.apache.org/index/community/discussion-forums.html) the team will be pleased to respond if that fit your needs. Regards